# Ubuntu 21.04 (Wayland) visual glitches in GUIs

Tags: wayland, 21.04, visual-artifacts

20.10 has no visual bugs and works fine but 21.04 has these visual bugs over all GUIs (Doesn't seem to effect actual gameplay). I've tried switching back to xorg, but that made no difference. I have an AMD RX 6700 XT with the default AMD drivers included in Ubuntu 21.04.

[Buggy Lunar client menu](https://streamable.com/p8wgfr)

[Buggy steam menu](https://streamable.com/pcihlo)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by completely deleting my drivers and reinstalling them.

Comment: How did you delete the drivers? Can you expand a bit?